# Telegram Python Bot - How to make menu after mentioning bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am making a bot using the python-telegram-bot library. How do I make a menu mentioning the bot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6OsT.png)

And how do I make a button, which when pressed inputs `"@bot_username "` in `telegram` client chat so the user can get the menu by pressing a button?

Here is my code:

```
# Define a function for /start command
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    if query is None:
        query = update.effective_message
    # Send the message with image and buttons
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Open Search Menu", callback_data="???")]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        photo=returnConfig()["General_Config"]["Image"],
        caption=f"Hey @{query.from_user.username}! Welcome back, how can I help you today?\n\nCheck out {returnConfig()['General_Config']['UpdatesGroup']} for instant updates, and {returnConfig()['General_Config']['ServicesList']} for all our sercices.",
        reply_markup=reply_markup,
    )
```

I couldn't find any information about it online.

Answer (score 0):

That's called [inline mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#inline-requests). You can find a PTB example [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.html#examples-inlinebot).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.